# Maximizing the information gain on a Gaussian RV with a noisy comparison question

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, information-theory, mutual-information

### The question

Let

- $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ be a random variable denoting the location of a target on the real line.
- $Y_a$ be a binary random variable encoding the (noisy) answer to the question: "is $X > a$ ?", with the following conditional distribution:
  $$p(y_a = 1 \mid X = x) = \sigma(x - a),$$
  where $\sigma(x)$ is a sigmoidal function, for example the logistic function $1 / [1 + \exp(-x)]$.

my question is a follows: **which value of $a$ should I choose in order to maximize the information I gain about $X$ by observing $Y_a$?**

More precisely, I am interested in maximizing the mutual information:

$$\max_a I(X, Y_a).$$

This can be understood as maximizing the expected reduction in the posterior's entropy: $I(X, Y_a) = H(X) - \mathbf{E}_{Y_a} [ H(X \mid Y_a = y) ]$

---

### My attempt at a solution

I am convinced that one should pick $a = 0$, i.e.:
$$I(X, Y_0) \ge I(X, Y_a) \quad \forall a \in \mathbf{R},$$
but I have not yet been able to prove it formally.

I started by rewriting the mutual information as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
I(X, Y_a) &= H(Y_a) - H(Y_a | X) \\
&= H \left[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \sigma(x - a) \mathcal{N}(x \mid 0, 1) dx \right]
- \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} H[\sigma(x - a)] \mathcal{N}(x \mid 0, 1) dx
\end{align}
$$
and then I took the derivative w.r.t $a$:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}I(X, Y_a) = \
    &\mathrm{logit} \left[ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \sigma(x - a) \mathcal{N}(x \mid 0, 1) dx \right]
    \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \sigma'(x - a) \mathcal{N}(x \mid 0, 1) dx \\
    &- \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathrm{logit}[\sigma(x - a)] \sigma'(x - a) \mathcal{N}(x \mid 0, 1) dx
\end{align}
$$

It is then easy to verify that $a = 0$ is a stationary point (in the first term, the integral inside the logit evaluates to $1/2$, and in the second term, we take the integral of an odd function). So $a = 0$ is at least a local maximum.

I haven't managed to show that this is the *only* zero of the derivative (Note that, clearly, $I(X, Y_a)$ is not concave in $a$). Numerical simulations indicate that there is no other zero, however.

Some other "facts" that I collected and that might be helpful:

- $I(X, Y_a) \to 0$ as $|a| \to \infty$
- If we pick the $\sigma(x - a) = \epsilon + (1-2\epsilon)\mathbf{1}_{\{X>a\}}$, i.e., a "noisy" indicator function the problem becomes much easier. I can show that
  $$I(X, Y_a) = H[\epsilon + (1-2\epsilon)\Phi(a)] - H(\epsilon),$$
  where $\Phi(a)$ is the Gaussian CDF. Then, $a=0$ is clearly the only maximizer.
- I know that $I(X, Y)$ is convex in $p_X$ and concave in $p_{Y \mid X}$. But that doesn't help here, I think, because my distributions are parametric (and don't form a convex set).

Comment: Does anyone have an idea how to improve this question? Is anything unclear?